# Need basic information on how to include a custom Python script into a compiled Linux image and have it execute on boot

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, kernel

Working with the QSXP-ML81 SOM from Ka-ro Electronics, we need to compile a custom Linux image and run it on the machine.  For the curious, the directions from Ka-ro on how to do this are here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qrrmbe2cuhnak9/Custom%20Image%20Setup%20%E2%80%94%20Ka-Ro%20electronics%20GmbH.pdf?dl=0.

The ultimate goal is to have a Python script included as part of the image so that it can be run when the SOM boots up.  As of now, when the SOM is running I can get a terminal going, download the script, and execute it, but this needs to happen without human intervention.  The directions from Ka-ro do not specify how this could be done.  I have completed a custom image using their directions and verified it works, so the missing step is to how to get our own scripts included.  I have done many searches along the lines of "include file in compiled Linux image" and not found any information on this topic.  For anyone who thinks they can help, be aware we are total Linux neophytes so any advice needs to be very explicit.